# Php live google chart

Tags: php, mysql

i'm working on a chart from mysql and i want to do it live or  to update itself every 10 sec.

My database is about weather and collects data through an arduino weather shield....
I can display the chart when i click on that page but i want to update the data that is recorded in the database every 5 seconds this is my code hope someone can help:

```
<?php
function tempf($input,$name){
global $conn;

echo ' <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
              <script type="text/javascript">
                google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
                google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
                function drawChart() {
                  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                    ["Year", "'.$name.'"],';
    $resultValue = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM daily ORDER BY timeStamp DESC LIMIT 200 ");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($resultValue)>0){
        while($rowValue = mysqli_fetch_array($resultValue)){
             echo '["'.$rowValue['timeStamp'].'", '.$rowValue[''.$input.''].'],';
        }
    }
     echo ']);

                  var options = {
                    title: "Graph"
                  };

                  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById("chart_div"));
                  chart.draw(data, options);
                }
              </script>
              <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px; margin-left:4.5cm; "></div>';

}


?>
```

i use this page to get the charts for every column in my mysql database
Thanks

Comment: Use javascript to refresh the page every 5 seconds

Comment: @kimbarcelona 
well i can do that but i have a live background and the charts uses a delay to display,so i cant use that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple to do that with Javascript without refreshing your page, replace your line chart.draw(data, options) by this:

```
function update(){

  timerId = setTimeout(function () {
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }, 5000);

}

update();
```

If you want more tuto on web development about javascript, jquery, and php take a look at: http://www.newvibe.ca/92weblessons